# Excel AddIn - Adding rows to an existing table

Tags: javascript, excel, office365, office-js, excel-addins

I'm having some troubles while using the Javascript Excel API to create an Excel AddIn.

**First issue:** 
Adding rows to an existing table with the [Excel Js library](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/develop/understanding-the-javascript-api-for-office): I create a table and add some rows; then the user can update table content with new data coming from a REST service (so resulting table rows can change: increase / decrease, or be the same).

**tl;dr;** I need to replace table rows with new ones.

That seems pretty simple: there's a `addRows` method in Table namespace ([reference](https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-js-docs-pr/blob/master/docs/excel/excel-add-ins-tables.md#add-rows-to-a-table)). 
But this won't work as expected: if the table already contains rows new ones will be added to the end, not replacing the existing ones.

Here the code:

```
const currentWorksheet = context.workbook.worksheets.getItemOrNullObject(
  "Sheet1"
)
let excelTable = currentWorksheet.tables.getItemOrNullObject(tableName)
if (excelTable.isNullObject) {
  excelTable = currentWorksheet.tables.add(tableRange, true /* hasHeaders */)
  excelTable.name = tableName
  excelTable.getHeaderRowRange().values = [excelHeaders]
  excelTable.rows.add(null, excelData)
} else {
  excelTable.rows.add(0, excelData)
}
```

I also tried to delete old rows, then adding new ones.

```
if (!excelTable.isNullObject) {
  for (let i = tableRows - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    // Deletes all table rows
    excelTable.rows.items[i].delete()
  }

  excelTable.rows.add(0, excelData)
}
```

But .. it works fine **only** if there isn't content below the columns of the table (no functions, other tables and so on).

---

I tried another method: using **ranges**. 
The first time I create the table, next ones I delete all rows, get the range of new data and insert the values:

```
if (excelTable.isNullObject) {
  excelTable = currentWorksheet.tables.add(tableRange, true /* hasHeaders */)
  excelTable.name = tableName
  excelTable.getHeaderRowRange().values = [excelHeaders]
  excelTable.rows.add(null, excelData)
} else {
  let actualRange, newDataRange
  const tableRows = excelTable.rows.items.length
  const tableColumns = excelTable.columns.items.length
  const dataRows = excelData.length
  const dataColumns = excelData[0].length

  actualRange = excelTable.getDataBodyRange()

  for (let i = tableRows - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    // Deletes all table rows
    excelTable.rows.items[i].delete()
  }

  newDataRange = actualRange.getAbsoluteResizedRange(dataRows, tableColumns)

  newDataRange.values = excelData
}
```

But there are still drawbacks with this solution.

It needs to be so hard to **add/edit/remove rows** in an Excel table?

---

**Second issue:** 
Using the same table, if the user decides to add some 'extra' columns (with a formula based on table values e.g.), do I need to fill this new columns with `null` data?

```
const tableColumns = excelTable.columns.items.length
const dataRows = excelData.length
const dataColumns = excelData[0].length

if (tableColumns > dataColumns) {
  let diff = tableColumns - dataColumns

  for (let i = 0; i < diff; i++) {
    for (let j = 0; j < dataRows; j++) {
      excelData[j].push(null)
    }
  }
}
```

Excel API can't handle this scenario?

Please, could you help me?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Does it expose Resize method and then write new data to that? Should overwrite existing.

Comment: @QHarr No, there are only 2 options: you can `delete()` the table or `add() / delete()` single rows

Comment: I think the **ranges** option above is your best option (create the table, next time delete all rows, get the range of new data and insert the values). It's a bit clumsy I agree, but gets the job done. You mentioned there are drawbacks with that approach - any other concerns beyond the fact it's a bit clumsy?

Comment: Thank you @DougMahugh! 
Yes, it's very clumsy, but it isn't the only issue: if I have another table under the one that I'm updating, the table will move up or down related to rows that I'm adding / removing. After several data reload the lower table will overlap the first one. 
Any suggestion related to this problem?

Comment: @Michael Zlatkovsky: do you have any suggestion about my issue?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your reporting.
Add table row API is just adding row to the table rows, not replace it.
What's more. I can't repro the issue with delete rows. Can you show me more details?

Comment: Ok, understood. So, if I need to replace table rows with new ones, how should I do that? The only solution, using Table API, is deleting all rows and then adding new ones?
To delete rows you need to load values from table data, as: ```excelTable.rows.load("values")
    excelTable.columns.load("values")```

Here there's a [Gist_example](https://gist.github.com/ATrogolo/938ccce2d29448b349c3ec989d53ea8e)